# How to stop processing other splits or the file itself, if at least one split fails in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a big CSV file, say 2GB (or say 10k lines) to be processed using map-reduce. Knowing that each block is 128MB, I have 16 blocks and hence 16 splits. As it is a text file, I am okay for multiple mappers to process different parts of the file (different splits) at the same time. The mapper count is default at 4, and hence 4 parts of the file are processed in parallel

The requirement is that, I don't want to process the file any further, or don't want to write the contents of the file to output folder, if at least one split fails. That is if at least one line of the CSV causes an error, I don't want the file to be processed any further, nor its output is needed. (This is because I can rectify the error and run it again fresh)

How do I do it?

I have extended `FileInputFormat` to override `isSplittable` method and returns true. If I return false, I know only one mapper will process the file - but I fear too much of network transfer will happen to process the file fully.

I tried `Counter`, but the issue is how will I let other mappers know that someone set a counter value because something failed

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Mappers are independent to each other, and there is no direct communication possible among them. Saying this, there is no direct way for mapper to communicate about the failure to other mappers.

If your concern is to cleanup, you may collect the status of the job at submission in the driver class.

```
boolean done = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

The value is done would be `false`, if the job failed. If it has failed (because one of the mapper threw an exception); just clean up the output directory, or fix the CSV programatically and rerun.

EDIT - Based on comments from OP

> The job is set to run till the end and finish gracefully. That is, all
>   exceptions are caught and logged, and thus mappers are not killed.
>   This means, job's finished state will always be SUCCESSFUL. This is
>   done to make sure that mapper won't fail at bad files, but proceed to
>   process good ones, till the last one.

In this case, you may use a counter (in mapper) to increase the count on the failure.

```
context.getCounter("my_group", "bad_record").increment(1);
```

When the job finishes, simply get the counter value in the driver class and mark the process as failed if it has a positive count.

```
long value= job.getCounters().getGroup("my_group").findCounter("bad_record").getValue();
```

- Please take care of Null check in the above code, in case none of the records are bad and the counter is not at all present.

EDIT - Adding another possible option

Through below code, it is possible to get an instance of job from context and try getting the counter value in the mapper (and stop processing the file further). But I am not sure, if the counter is actually available *during* the execution or only *after* the execution ends.

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
Job currentJob = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
long val=currentJob.getCounters().findCounter("bad_record").getValue();
```

I have not tested it. Please try and let me know.

Comment: The job is set to run till the end and finish gracefully. That is, all exceptions are caught and logged, and thus mappers are not killed. This means, job's finished state will always be SUCCESSFUL. This is done to make sure that mapper won't fail at bad files, but proceed to process good ones, till the last one.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. As I said in the original question, I already tried Counter. So I know the code too. But my question was, how to even stop processing the file at all  when an error is found (or counter incremented). That is, I need to tell the other running mappers that one mapper has found an Error in one split of file A, and hence incremented the Counter. So all mappers working on splits from file A (as per OPost, there are 16 splits)  should stop working on this file's splits anymore, and proceed with next file.

Comment: @Thomas Kindly re-read my edit. You are trying to use counter to inform failure to other mappers. **That is not possible in any way**. I am using counter to flag a bad record. Once all mappers are completed (which according to you will anyway complete, because the program is not allowed to throw an exception), the counter in driver let u take action. One thing you must understand that the only way to fail a map reduce is to break it by throwing exception (which you are preventing). Even though you break a mapper, MR job would try 2 more times, and by that time other mappers may just complete.

Comment: @Thomas I have added one hack, but not tested. Kindly try and let me know, if it works.